# How to filter json api data with condition using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

i'm getting this data from backend api. How can i add filter into json data? For Example if user want keywords which has search volume more than 20000. how can i do that? i appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Please try to clarify your question and show some example code or what you want to achieve. It's way too broad.

Comment: `i'm getting this data` what data (JSON)? There's only an image of the rendered view. Also, what have you tried to filter it? Have you tried `.filter()` ?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing filtering on the client site, if there are so many entries: try designing your queries such that the results can be paginated, and if you want to perform filtering, try doing it on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

When gathering data from a backend api, in react here's how you would do it:

```js
const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = React.useState(null);

function fetchData() {
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setFetchedData(data));
};


// loads data initially on page load
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
  }, [])
  

//use this function to tie to an "onChange" or "onClick" event when submitting the values.
function filterData(inputValue) {
  if(inputValue === "") return;

  
  const filteredData = fetchedData.filter((value) => {
  return value.SEARCH_INDEX_VALUE_HERE >= inputValue
  }
  
  return filteredData;
}
```

You can find a good description from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

This is given that the data returned is an array of objects, and the the SEARCH_INDEX_VALUE_HERE is whatever column key that is provided to the data you're filtering. In your case, it would be the "Search value" field I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method of JavaScript like this.

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function (item)
{
  return item.Search_volume >=20000;
         
}
);
```